# How can I make effect at the bottom of input while hovering?

Tags: html, css, input

I'm looking for some techlogy that I can make an effect at the bottom of `<input>` element when I hover on it. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for `box-shadow` property. Like this:

```css
input {
  width: 280px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 3px inset;
}

input:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px cyan;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Why does it only work at the bottom?

Comment: @Babylon I just make it as same as the image you give.

Comment: That's where I get confused, I want the entire border to look like that and it looks like that.     input:hover {   
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(76, 201, 240, 1);
        }    This is my code.